# iPhone - Animating when user blows into mic

Tags: xcode, animation, microphone

I want to implement in my project the blow mic detection, and I found [this](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) tutorial.
But I didn't start to use it.. I just wanted to know for now if its possible, for example to change images with animation by blowing the mic, like making fog effect or something like that & how to do that?

Anyone maybe have a little example or can help?